# After clicking on vba button on parent sheet, it jumps to feeder sheet automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I assign a button on sheet("NPS") to calculate and copy data from another sheet("Pay_Slip"). My vba calculate and copy correctly but after doing job it jumps to feeder sheet i.e. sheet("Pay_Slip"). I want that parent Sheet i.e. sheet('NPS") remains open. Help me to find the error!
My code is

```
Sub NPS()
Dim i As Integer
Dim LROW As Long
Dim LR As Long

LROW = Sheets("NPS").Range("C200").End(xlUp).Row
LR = Sheets("Pay_Slip").Range("B500").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Pay_Slip").Unprotect Password:="@"
Sheets("NPS").Unprotect Password:="@"

For i = 5 To LROW
If Len(Sheets("Pay_Slip").Range("B" & i)) = 8 Then
Sheets("NPS").Range("B" & i + 6).Value = Sheets("Pay_Slip").Range("D" & i).Value
Sheets("NPS").Range("C" & i + 6).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX(emp,MATCH(RC[-1],NAME,0),MATCH(R9C3,data,0))"
Sheets("NPS").Range("D" & i + 6).Value = Sheets("Pay_Slip").Range("AE" & i).Value
Sheets("NPS").Range("E" & i + 6).Value = Sheets("Pay_Slip").Range("I2:K2").Value
Sheets("NPS").Range("F" & i + 6).Value = Sheets("Pay_Slip").Range("R" & i).Value
Sheets("NPS").Range("G" & i + 6).Value = Sheets("Pay_Slip").Range("AH" & i).Value
Sheets("NPS").Range("H" & i + 6).Value = Sheets("Pay_Slip").Range("AB" & i).Value
Sheets("NPS").Range("I" & i + 6).Value = Sheets("NPS").Range("F" & i + 6).Value + Sheets("NPS").Range("H" & i + 6).Value

Else: Sheets("NPS").Range("B" & i + 6 & ":I" & i + 16).ClearContents

End If
Next i

Sheets("NPS").Range("B" & LROW + 7).Value = "Signature"
Sheets("NPS").Range("B" & LROW + 9).Value = "DDO" & "/" & Range("H7").Value
Sheets("NPS").Range("G" & LROW + 7).Value = "Signature"
Sheets("NPS").Range("G" & LROW + 9).Value = "Principal"

Sheets("Pay_Slip").Protect Password:="@"
Sheets("NPS").Protect Password:="@"
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works for me.  Do you have any `Change` (or similar) events that could be executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can set it active by using this method:

```
Sheets("NPS").Activate
```

Although that doesn't really answer "why" the second sheet goes active, it should get you to the goal line.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion